# Use IntValue in if-statement to calculate?

Tags: iphone, ios, if-statement

I'm really new to programming with objective c and so I hope that you can help me. I want to use 3 intValues from textfields to calculate. I have done it like this:

```
-(int)om{
NSNumber *Om1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self.Textfield1.text intValue]];
return [Om1 intValue];}

-(int)on{
NSNumber *On1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self.Textfield2.text intValue]];
return [On1 intValue];}

-(int)lv{
NSNumber *Lv1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self.Textfield3.text intValue]];
return [Lv1 intValue];}
```

Now I want to use an if-statement to calculate the sum and run a message on the screen. I want calculate whether Om1 + On1 is less than Lv1+4. Is it a good idea to use the if-statement?

Comment: `if([self lv]+4 > [self om] + [self on]){
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Om1 + On1 is less than Lv1 + 4" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okey" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write simpler function. I.E.:

```
-(int) om {
    return [self.Textfield1.text intValue];
}
```

There is no point in creating a `NSNumber` instance just to return value.

You can use an `if` statement to do what you want:

```
if (([self om] + [self on]) < ([self lv] + 4)) {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is just to use variables, no need to use NSNumbers.  Using variable is perhaps more clear than three methods.

```
int om = [self.Textfield1.text intValue];
int on = [self.Textfield2.text intValue];
int lv = [self.Textfield3.text intValue];

if ((om + on) < (lv + 4)) {
    // your code here
}
```